# Using vanilla javascript library with electron/typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron

Im trying to include [this library](https://github.com/datejs/Datejs) into my electron app and it works when I start my electron app in development mode (`electron-forge start`). But when I build my app using `electron-builder --win` I get an error saying `Date.today is not a function`.

I included the library in my index.html like so

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Datejs/build/date-de-DE.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having not seen any code or folder structure, I am going to take a guess and say that when your app is built, Electron doesn't see the path to `js/Datejs/build/date-de-DE.js` because it's running directory is in a different folder than the `js` directory. In other words, the `js` directory was most likely excluded from the build process.

Are you sure that you are including all the right files in the build process?

Check out the [documentation](https://www.electron.build/configuration/contents) to see how to set the config to include different files

Comment: Good guess, this seems to be the solution. I didn't try including the directory in the build process I just removed the library and used momentjs.